# How to remove a part of a column using awk

Tags: awk, date, sort

I have this :

```
2018:01:02-23:52:48
2018:01:02-23:52:48
2018:01:02-23:52:48
2018:01:03-09:26:20
2018:01:03-09:26:20
```

I want to keep the date, but not the hour in order to sort the number of messages per day :

```
2018:01:02
2018:01:02
2018:01:02
2018:01:03
2018:01:03
```

I want to do it with `awk` if possible.

Comment: If this is the only data in your file then "awk -F- '{ print $1 }' filename" should do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- awk

  ```
  awk -F- '$0=$1' file
  ```
- cut

  ```
  cut -d- -f1 file
  ```
- sed

  ```
  sed 's/-.*//' file
  ```
- perl

  ```
  perl -pe 's/-.*//' file
  ```

Comment: Cut is the right tool, +1 :)

Comment: cut is the right tool if that's the one and only thing you want to do with the input lines.  if you want to do anything else as well, use awk or perl. or even sed.

Answer (score 7):

Simply with **`awk`**:

```
awk -F'-' '{ print $1 }' file
```

- `-F'-'` - treat `-` (dash) as field separator

---

But in your simple case `grep` approach would be even simpler:

```
grep -o '^[^-]*' file
```

Comment: I forgot to write that I already tried this specific awk command. And it doesn't work..

Comment: @Namless, make sure you have posted the actual input and check your code for errors

Answer (score 4):

If the input *only* contains the timestamps, then it's easy to set the dash as the field separator and only print the first field:

```
$ awk -F- '{print $1}' input
2018:01:02
2018:01:02
```

But if you also have something else in there, say `input2` contains

```
2018:01:02-23:52:48 some data 
2018:01:02-23:52:48 something else
```

then that would drop the rest of the line, and for other processing, you might not want to change the field separator either. But you can do a simple substitution on the first field and print the resulting line:

```
$ awk '{sub(/-.*/, "", $1)} 1' input2
2018:01:02 some data
2018:01:02 something else
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F- ' { print $1 } ' | sort | uniq -c
```

Will also do the summation for you:

```
  3 2018:01:02
  2 2018:01:03
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same by below awk substring method

```
 awk '{print substr($1,1,10)}'  filename
```

Output

```
2018:01:02
2018:01:02
2018:01:02
2018:01:03
2018:01:03
```

Answer (score 0):

by gnu awk

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[:-]"} {print $1":"$2":"$3 }' file
```

or

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]+"}{print $1":"$2":"$3 }' file
```

may change date separator printout above to one liking

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[:-]"}{print $1"/"$2"/"$3 }' file
2018/01/02
2018/01/02
2018/01/02
2018/01/03
2018/01/03
```

Answer (score 0):

Done in python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import re
h=open('filename','r')
for  i in h:
    print i.split('-')[0].strip()
```

output

```
2018:01:02
2018:01:02
2018:01:02
2018:01:03
2018:01:03
```